# arguments object is of zero length even after I can access its properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Why the arguments object is of zero length when I have pass parameters to the function and even when I can access its properties?
I'm talking about the arguments object that all javascript functions implement, you can access the function arguments from it. You can know more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments.

What happen is that when I print the length of the arguments object to the console it says that it has cero length however when I access it from inside my function (component) I still can use one of its properties. You can read the comments in the code below for more details.

I'm using react with typescript.

```
interface Props{
id: string;
className?: string;    
}

export const Buttons: React.FC<Props> = function(){


  function arg(){

    console.log("Funciona");
    console.log("arguments object: "+arguments);
    {/*This prints to the console that the arguments objects is of cero (0) length*/}
    {/*Even when is posible to access
    the id property that I have passed from App component*/}
    console.log("arguments object: "+arguments.length);
    console.log("arguments object: "+arguments[0]);

    for(let i=0; i < arguments.length; i++){

      {/*It will never enter the for loop*/}

      console.log("arguments object: "+arguments[i]);

    }

  }{/*end arg*/}

  React.useEffect(

    ()=>{

      window.setTimeout(arg, 5000);

    },
    []

  );

  return(

    {/*This will work as I'm  able to see the id from the dev tools*/}
    <section id={arguments[0].id}>{}

      <div className="container">

        <p>Hello World</p>

      </div>

    </section>

  );
}
```

Here I pass the id prop:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (

    <div className="App">

      <Buttons id="buttons" />

    </div>

  );
}
```

Comment: Do not add spam text to your post to get around the requirement that asks you to explain more of the problem - instead, please *actually explain the problem in more detail*, such as what sort of debugging you've tried that isn't working. It could also be helpful to look up how to create a [MCVE] - consider trimming out code that's not directly related to the problem.

Comment: @CertainPerformance All the code is relevant to the problem, but yes I will add more details now that I realize that the question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to understand your question?

Are you trying to access the *id props* by doing *arguments[0].id*?

You can access the "arguments" of a component (called props in react) by:

Replacing:

```
export const Buttons: React.FC<Props> = function(){
```

By:

```
export const Buttons: React.FC<Props> = function(props){
```

And calling

```
props.id
```

Good luck

Comment: Yes but it is the normal behavior. The "arguments" var in your return is not the same that in your arg() function. The scope is not the same. In your component, it takes the "props" argument. In your arg() function. it takes the arg() arguments, which is null. Please in your arg() function, use "this.props" to access the same arguments that the component arguments

Comment: It throws this error "'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.  TS2683" I also tried this.arguments without the props keyword. I want to be able to access the arguments object of the component without passing props to my component the same way I'm accessing it from the return statement.

Comment: I did not notice it was a functionnal component, sorry, my mistake. I just updated my answer so you can refer to it properly.